# Where is "download publish profile" in the new Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the old Azure Portal, I used to download the publish profile (which included FTP username/password) for App Services using the menu shown here.

How do I get this in the new Azure Portal? Ultimately, how can I get my FTP user/pass for my App Service?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it is right on the website`s blade.

[image]

and regarding to FTP address and username, you should be able to see the details from setting --> properties

[image]

Comment: Thanks, still getting used to the layout.

Comment: May be hidden behind the ellipsis (...)

Comment: If you want to get a publish profile for your entire subscription(s) you can run the following in a PowerShell terminal: `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`

Answer (score 9):

I found it just in the main menu under Overview. Yeah, hidden firstly so you need to click ...More.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Just Here "Get Publish Profile"

[image: Get publish profile]

Answer (score 4):

In the new portal, Goto

**Azure Portal -> Your web app -> Overview Tab**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be found in App Service as follows

[Click here to see the Download Publish Profile link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Emj.png)

Thank you