# How to Deploy Excel AddIn created with office.js

Tags: excel, vsto, office-js

Created Excel AddIn with VSTO and office.js, not sure how to deploy to other computers.. For Normal Excel AddIn created Visual Studio Setup project, for this one tried to create WebSetup project provided by Visual Studio, but not working..
Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2014/01/15/publishing-apps-for-office-and-sharepoint-to-windows-azure-websites/.

In the step where the blog talks about downloading an Azure publish profile (if you're targeting Azure), see [Where is "download publish profile" in the new Azure Portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191234/where-is-download-publish-profile-in-the-new-azure-portal).

Comment: Thanks Mike for response.. my application is not using Azure, it is simple Web AddIn that integrates with Excel and provides search facility for organization using REST based APIs, this AddIn is developed using Visual Studio office.js, now to deploy to other machine, created one VS Installer Setup project.. it is installing but when I open Excel it is not showing in Task Panes of Excel... it shows when I start excel from Visual studio (F5).. Hope I clarified my requirement.. How to invoke WebAddIn in Excel at other user machine after installing..

Comment: If we have any link for steps to create setup and deploy Excel Web AddIn, that will be great.. I have normal Excel AddIn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx but for excel web addin not able to locate

Comment: If by an Excel Web Addin you mean the new "Office Add-ins" that use Office.js -- it's a completely different project and deplopyment type.  You don't use a regular installer, as there is actually nothing to install.  Instead you need to publish the website somewhere (i.e., Azure), and then distribute the manifest file (i.e., via the store -- or a corporate catalog, or a network share, etc.)  See more in the link I gave, and in http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish

Comment: @Madhur did you resolve the issue? I am also facing the same. Unfortunately you can't deploy on linux server for hosting. Just curuios if you have resolved the issue. If yes then how

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft On the deployment website it indicates deployment is by Centralized Deployment via the Microsoft 365 admin center. Although it doesn't give instruction how to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment

Comment: @SteveTomlin, I have left the Extensibility team earlier this year -- but if I might recommend, the bottom of that docs page has a "Submit and view feedback for" section, where you can file a bug for this particular documentation page, and hopefully someone will be able to get back to you with more details. All the best!

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Thanks I will look into this. Thanks for reply.