# In Azure, how do I deploy functionapp code without using git?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-node-sdk

I created a Resource Manager template which has the Resources to run a function app basically using the default template for this purpose and I can manually copy files to my File Storage under `sites\wwwroot` and when I curl the functionapp it works.

But what I'm wondering is, what is the right way to deploy a bunch of files to update the actual functionapp, but not using git. I can see some examples of how to use git but my problem is that I want to have all my functions in a single repo not a bunch of smaller repos (I want a monorepo).

In Azure you just upload your code in a .gz file to S3 then when creating the lambda you give it a path to the zip. And then later there is a simple API that you can call to push up a new zip and presto.

What is the equivalent API in azure to just give it a zip and have it unpack the files in the right directory?

**EDIT:**

I managed to figure it out finally, the top answer was essentially right but there were a few extra steps I had to figure out so I'll put those here.

The specific doc on curl is [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-curl). My issue thread with the team is [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2582).

The actual curl call I used is this:

```
$ curl -XPUT --data-binary @index.js.zip "https://abc:xyz@ugh.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/hello"
```

Notes on this:

- You must use `--data-binary`, `-d` results in a bad payload
- To create the zip in bash I used: `$ zip index.js.zip index.js`
- `abc:xyz` is the deployment username and password
- The right path to send is `site/wwwroot/hello` where `hello` is the name of the function.

You can set the username and password in the azure portal UI ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment)) but you can also set it with the `azure-cli` like so:

```
$ az login
$ az webapp deployment user set --user-name abc --password xyz
```

And that was the trick, once you've setup the deployment credentials you can use them in basic auth to call the kudu api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Rest API to deploy Function App is also allowed in Azure. We could use the following Rest API to do that. We could get more detail info from  [Kudu REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API). We could get the ftp use and password from publish file, about how to publish file, please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191234/where-is-download-publish-profile-in-the-new-azure-portal/34191267).

```
PUT https://{user}:{password}@{FunctionAppname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/{path}  # example path:site/wwwroot
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out last night after a late night hacking but this is essentially right so I'm marking you as the answer. I updated my question with more details on my solution.

Comment: Also try the new [zip deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file) API as we discussed on [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2589)