# Retrieving php project from Azure

Tags: php, azure

Our website coded in php language was designed by some third party. Our whole project code with its database is in Azure. We now want to make changes to it and update it but we do not know how to retrieve php code of website from Azure. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Azure Subscription where you app is hosted, you have several options.

1. Download the [publishing profile and use FTP/S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191234/where-is-download-publish-profile-in-the-new-azure-portal).  This file will have FTP username and password.
2. Use the Kudu Environment (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net)
3. Use the App Editor (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev)
4. If Continuous Deployment was configured you could grab the code from the repo (assuming you have access to the repo).

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have access to subscription. It will be really helpful if you describe the 1st, 2nd or 3rd option a little bit in detail.